# PHP - Zenfolio API - Error for method LoadGroupHierarchy

Tags: php, image-gallery

I am trying to bring photos from Zenfolio database using PHP. I keep receiving this error
Zenfolio API Error for method LoadGroupHierarchy: E_NOSUCHOBJECT (Error Code: 90009)

I am using admin username and password. Any ideas why?

Comment: See this: https://github.com/lildude/phpZenfolio/issues/6

Comment: I did try that and did not work. Thanks though.